# Sql server: Login failed for user 'payroll'

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, iis-7

I have a test server on which i am trying to move my web application from a different server.

**Old Server Specs:**

Windows Server 2000

Sql Server 2000

IIS6

**New Server Specs**

Windows Server 2008
Sql Server 2008
IIS 7

The problem is that on the new server I am able to connect through SQL Server Management Studio with a Local Login account called payroll and its password.

The problem is that when I am trying to use my web application to connect to the server it gives me an error login failed for user payroll.
taking into consideration the following

1. the connection string in my web.config has the correct username and password.
2. in my web.config I have authentication="Windows"
3. in the IIS7 the pool I am using is ASP.NETV4.0
4. the Identity for this pool is "Local system"
5. in the IIS7 Authentication is Windows Authentication, Anonymous Authentication is disabled.
6. the user is added in the Sql server logins and mapped to be db_Owner for all my databases.

Thanks in advance.
Baher.

Comment: What do you mean by Local Login account? Is it Windows authentication or SQL?

Comment: I am connecting to SQL using Sql authentication .. using a username and password which are provided in my connection string.